# data-src with ngIf in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I am uploading image by Angular. But the link code will not show a demo image with 200*200 when model.logoUrl is null.

```
<div id="carousel-match-generic" *ngIf="statusType=='Edit'" [ngStyle]="{width: '210px'}">
<div  class="fileupload admin-form fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
   <div class="fileupload-preview thumbnail mb15">
     <img *ngIf="model.logoUrl" src="{{model.logoUrl}}" width="200" alt="holder">
     <img *ngIf="!model.logoUrl" data-src="holder.js/200x200" alt="holder">                                      
   </div>
   <span class="button btn-system btn-file btn-block ph5">                                        
   <span *ngIf="!model.logoUrl">上传LOGO</span>
   <span *ngIf="model.logoUrl">修改LOGO</span>
   <input type="file" name="logoUrl" id="inputImage" (change)="fileChanged($event)">
   </span>
 </div>
```

The result is

```
<img _ngcontent-c0="" alt="holder" data-src="holder.js/200x200">
```

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: use `src` instead of `data-src` i would say